# Compare files from two folders using HASH SHA1 in BATCH

Tags: batch-file, hash, certutil

I have this batch code but it is wrong, what I need is to see on screen the name of the files in folder2 that are not in folder1 comparing them with your HASH SHA1. Temporary files are in the same directory.
I appreciate your comments

```
@echo off
cd folder1
FOR /F "Delims=" %%A in ('DIR /B/A-D *.*') DO (
    certUtil -hashfile "%%A" SHA1 | findstr /VI "HASH"| findstr /VI "certutil"
) >>folder2\output.tmp

cd folder2
FOR /F "Delims=" %%B in ('DIR /B/A-D *.* ^|Findstr /VEIL ".tmp"') DO (
    certUtil -hashfile "%%B" SHA1 | findstr /VI "HASH"| findstr /VI "certutil" >>output2.tmp
    FOR /F "Delims=" %%C in ('TYPE output2.tmp^|findstr /XLIV /G:output.tmp') DO (echo "%%B") 
)
```

Comment: What happens if we make comments, will you reply positively or ignore them as with your last question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another solution that uses no temporary files.  Instead, it creates a sort of associative array like `f|filename.ext=hash`.  All the hashes are stored as variables, and the series of variables can be enumerated with `set "f|"`.  Basically, this makes it easy to get a list of hashes tied to filenames in directory 1, then use this list to compare directory 2.  If an expected variable is undefined, then the file in directory 2 does not exist in directory 1.  If it is defined, then compare the hashes and undefine it.  Whatever is left defined at the end indicates a file exists in directory 1 but not in directory 2.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

if "%~2"=="" goto usage

pushd "%~1" || goto usage
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:-d') do (
    for /f %%x in ('certutil -hashfile "%%~I" ^| find /v ":"') do set "f|%%~nxI=%%~x"
)
popd

pushd "%~2" || goto usage
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:-d') do (
    if not defined f^|%%~nxI (
        echo %%~nxI does not exist in %~nx1\
    ) else (
        for /f %%x in ('certutil -hashfile "%%~I" ^| find /v ":"') do (
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            if not "%%~x"=="!f|%%~nxI!" (
                echo %%~nxI hash mismatch
            )
            endlocal
            set "f|%%~nxI="
        )
    )
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=|=" %%I in ('cmd /c set "f|" 2^>NUL') do (
    echo %%I does not exist in %~nx2\
)

goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 dir1 dir2
echo compares files in dir1 with those in dir2.
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot !!

Comment: I have a problem with the code you sent and I hope you can help me.
When I use the file name variable with the hash **"f|%%~nxI=%%~x"** only the hash of the last file is saved and I can not compare

Comment: @Danielle Looks like you're comparing the variable name to the hash.  Isn't it supposed to be `"!f|%%~nxI!==%%~x"`?  Or maybe I need a little more context to understand the problem.

Comment: For example, if I have two files in the directory one, file1.txt and file2.txt when I put the variables it should do `f | file1.txt = 1111111` and `f | file2.txt = 2222`, but when comparing them in the other loop `f | file1 .txt = 2222` and `f | file2.txt = 2222`. What it does is copy the value of the last file for all the other variables. I hope you understand me and you can help me

Answer (score 3):

- certutil hash has no colon the other lines do.
- a file with only hashes doesn't make sense without the corresponding file
- the following batch creates hash filename pairs for both folders
- additionally each hash from folder2 is checked if present in folder1 - if not it is echoed to the screen.

---

```
@echo off
Set Dir1=A:\
Set Dir2=Q:\Test\2017\08\03\

PushD "%Dir1%"
(FOR /F "Delims=" %%A in ('DIR /B/A-D *.*'
 ) DO For /f "delims=" %%B in (
 'certUtil -hashfile "%%A" SHA1 ^| findstr /V ":"'
 ) Do Echo %%B %%~fA
)> "%Dir2%\output1.tmp"
PopD

PushD "%Dir2%"
Type Nul >output2.tmp
FOR /F "Delims=" %%A in ('DIR /B/A-D *.* ^|Findstr /LIVE ".tmp"'
) DO For /f "delims=" %%B in ('certUtil -hashfile "%%A" SHA1 ^| findstr /V ":"') Do (
       >> output2.tmp Echo %%B %%~fA
       Findstr "%%B" output1.tmp >Nul 2>&1 || Echo Hash %%B not in "%Dir1%" File %%~fA 
     )
)
PopD
```

Sample run:

```
> Q:\Test\2017\08\03\SO_45494397.cmd
Hash fcfd29ab1ba8b64411d5ce461a35f07907862533 not in "A:\" File Q:\Test\2017\08\03\Get-EpubMetaInfo.ps1
Hash aa37d47dc96380532c88559045b6c3fa080e2556 not in "A:\" File Q:\Test\2017\08\03\Get-MSebooks.ps1
Hash ae29aeca5a433993ec854ddea6d8469516d2293c not in "A:\" File Q:\Test\2017\08\03\Handle-ZipFile.psm1
Hash 2d0d7fc7927f007b8aba4032d1c9fe86074ec8a1 not in "A:\" File Q:\Test\2017\08\03\SO_45494397.cmd
```

Sample output_.tmp

```
> Type output1.tmp
c10937240668c7c09dbac247b5cb0e30f027cfe6 A:\SO_45490060.cmd
47c005b12889d32107b53bdbd16e94f029d330c4 A:\SO_45491838.cmd
af6cccbeec7b80cbb37143316bd910bf6dcf622e A:\SO_45494397.cmd

> Type output2.tmp
fcfd29ab1ba8b64411d5ce461a35f07907862533 Q:\Test\2017\08\03\Get-EpubMetaInfo.ps1
aa37d47dc96380532c88559045b6c3fa080e2556 Q:\Test\2017\08\03\Get-MSebooks.ps1
ae29aeca5a433993ec854ddea6d8469516d2293c Q:\Test\2017\08\03\Handle-ZipFile.psm1
c10937240668c7c09dbac247b5cb0e30f027cfe6 Q:\Test\2017\08\03\SO_45490060.cmd
47c005b12889d32107b53bdbd16e94f029d330c4 Q:\Test\2017\08\03\SO_45491838.cmd
52b8e933411859e450fde3e8735658d9f52159b0 Q:\Test\2017\08\03\SO_45494397.cmd
```

Comment: All files are different and I can not see any files. Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new in batch :(

Comment: Nice idea to `findstr /v ":"` the output of `certutil`.  +1.