# variables in two for loop batch

Tags: batch-file

Previously someone had helped me with something similar, but I still have problems.
I have an error and I do not know how to fix it.
What I want to do is a BATCH and compare the name of the variables and the size of them.

```
setlocal
FOR /F "Delims=" %%A in ('TYPE name.tmp') DO (
    FOR /F "Tokens=5 Delims= " %%B in ('TYPE size.tmp') DO (
        set "f|%%~nxA=%%~B"
    )
)
CHCP 65001 >NUL
FOR /F "Delims=" %%A in ('DIR /B *.*^|Findstr /VE ".tmp"^|Findstr /VE ".ini"') DO (
    if not defined f^|%%A (
        echo %%A
    ) else (
        setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
            echo.%%A "%%~zA" "!f|%%A!"
        endlocal
    )
)
```

What the code does, in the first directory I have two temporary files, one with the file size and the other with the name respectively and I make a variable **f|filename=size**.
And in the second directory I have to see what files are called the same and if they have the same name, see the larger file.
Everything works fine, but when using **!F|%%~nxA!**, the variables are not stored as I want.

output ...

```
file2.txt "1948" "120"
file1.txt "120" "120"
```

That's how it should be

```
file2.txt "1948" "1948"
file1.txt "120" "120"
```

When the variable is not defined (this means that in name.tmp there is a file called the same as in the acutal directory), it does an ECHO.

But if the file is defined (the file is in name.tmp and in the directory) I want to see the size of the acutal directory and what is in size.tmp.
The number of files in name.tmp and size.tmp is the same.

But in the variable only the last size is saved

Comment: Please don't put `|`s in variable names. That breaks everything.

Comment: @SomethingDark It's [rojo's code somehow crumbled from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45496719/6811411)

Comment: @LotPings - I suppose the quotes prevent the pipe from breaking things... now I guess this question is just the result of the classic "try to pair up each line in two separate files but you nested the `for` loops instead" problem. I think. We aren't told what the end result of the code actually is. I still stand by my recommendation to not use the pipe in variable names, though.

Comment: Are you aware that your code intends to output each non `.tmp` and non `.ini` file name in your current directory except for those with a file size of less than or equal to the fifth token of the last non empty line from `size.tmp`?

Comment: @SomethingDark  The variables must be saved f | file1.txt = 34 f | file2.txt = 78 etc. But only the last file size is saved f | file1.txt = 78 f | file2.txt = 78. That's my problem

Comment: @LotPings The variables must be saved f | file1.txt = 34 f | file2.txt = 78 etc. But only the last file size is saved f | file1.txt = 78 f | file2.txt = 78. That's my problem

Comment: @Danielle, are you telling us that you want the script to check each file with each size until all files and all sizes are exhausted? Could you not get all files named within `name.tmp` from the current directory ordered by size, and select the largest? or is that not what you need?

Comment: @compo For example, if I have two files, file1.txt and file2.txt when I put the variables it should do `f | file1.txt = 1111111` and `f | file2.txt = 2222`, but when comparing them in the other loop `f | file1 .txt = 2222` and `f | file2.txt = 2222`. What it does is copy the value of the last file for all the other variables. I hope you understand me and you can help me

Comment: @Danielle, I know what the code you've provided does, I'm just not clear what it is you actually need to do. From your shown code it appears as if you may need the `ChCp` line and the third `For` loop included within the previous `For` loop construct not after it.

Comment: @Compo I just updated the question